# moment.js and deprecated warning. timestamp to moment date object

Tags: momentjs

I've read thru various posts on here in regards to similiar issues but none have solved my problem.

I manipulate the moment.js date object, and then store it as timestamp.

BUT, when I try to read in that timestamp again, I get that deprecated warning.

""Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info."

I've tried toDate(), format(), moment(myTimeStamp, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');  --> all generate the warning...

So, for example, my timestamp will look like this:

const timestamp = '1458586740000'

when I read that back and try to parse out the month/day/year, then the hour/min am/pm, etc... I need to get that timestamp into a moment.js object. Nothing is working for me. Any ideas.

How can I get this timestamp: '1458586740000', into a moment.js object so I can extract date date from it as I need?

EDIT: this is how I am storing the timestamp. So I would need to retrieve it from this.

```
let timeStamp = Moment(state[_Date])
                           .add({ hour: state[AMPM] === 'PM'
                                      ? +state[Hour] + 12
                                      : state[Hour] ,
                                  minute: state[Min] }).format('x')
```

Comment: Did you try `moment.unix(timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY")`?

Comment: Did you try reading the linked issue? *"If you really want that behavior just do `moment(new Date("random string that contains date"))`"*.

Comment: So ultimately the variable timeStamp gets stored in a database, and then pulled back out again and parsed? I'm almost sure something is wrong with the data you are ultimately passing to the moment constructor, but I don't know what that would be based on this code. This will give you a unix offset as a string which should be fine. Need to know from the debugger exactly what is being passed into the moment constructor. I think you maybe have extraneous leading characters or something.

Comment: I mean, it is parsing fine as I am able to get it out of the db, and deal with the data... its just that error that comes up: "Deprecation warning...".

Comment: If you hop in moment's Gitter I can probably talk to you this afternoon. Might be easier than working through it in SO comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X token indicates a unix timestamp in seconds, and the x token indicates a unix millisecond timestamp (offset). 
You appear to have a millisecond timestamp, so you would make a moment out of it by doing the following:

```
var a = moment('1458586740000', 'x')
```

It works without ' as well:

```
var a = moment(1458586740000, 'x')
```

You can also not specify the x and it should work:

```
moment(1458586740000)
```

Because you have a unix offset (milliseconds), not a unix timestamp (seconds), moment.unix is not what you want.

Then you can do the following:

```
a.format()
"2016-03-21T13:59:00-05:00"
```

Or you can use any of the other formatting tokens listed here to output whatever result you would like: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Based on the code you presented, I think you may be having problems because your timestamp is stored as a string (in ''). Parsing as a string causes an invalid date error, because it attempts to match ISO 8601 format and fails. Specifying that 'x' token will cause it to assume unix offset and work correctly.

Comment: thanks - but it didn't work, and yeah - I tried this approach previously. So, yeah I have a string that is representive of this: See my updated original post. This is how i "store" it, perhaps it can add insight on how i need to extract it.

Comment: The key here for me was to parseInt as the number was a string.